# observe osx application's state(opening, quitting)

Tags: objective-c, macos

how can I get notified at my app while the specify application is opening or closing?

for example, I need do something in my app when iTunes is quitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe to the NSWorkspace notifications `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` and `NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification`.